# インストールした覚えが無い core-js に関する警告が出る

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

npm関係
pugをglobal install後、ローカルにcliをインストールしたら、変な警告が出た。

> npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer
> maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues.
> Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js
> versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is
> polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please,
> upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

なんとなく和訳

> core-jsアプデしろ

core-jsなんて今まで使ったことがなかった（babelは使ったことなない）
global、localのどこにもインストールされていない。
奇妙で少々怖い

これはなぜ私のPCにいるのか
これは一体何なのか

Comment: 参考: [core-jsがメンテされていない理由→プロジェクトは継続する](https://qiita.com/yumetodo/items/eaf3b97aeae3d8c4a07e)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> global、localのどこにもインストールされていない。
> 奇妙で少々怖い

npmの依存関係は複雑怪奇になりがちです。なので、知らないパッケージに依存していることはいたって一般的です。(このせいでサプライチェーン攻撃に脆弱な面もありますが)

npm v7以降であれば、依存関係の理由をボトムアップで取得できる[explain](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-explain)サブコマンドが使用できます。エイリアスは`why`なのでこちらのほうが覚えやすいかも。

```
$  npm explain core-js
core-js@2.6.12
node_modules/core-js
  core-js@"^2.4.0" from babel-runtime@6.26.0
  node_modules/babel-runtime
    babel-runtime@"^6.26.0" from babel-types@6.26.0
    node_modules/babel-types
      babel-types@"^6.26.0" from constantinople@3.1.2
      node_modules/constantinople
        constantinople@"^3.0.1" from pug-attrs@2.0.4
        node_modules/pug-attrs
          pug-attrs@"^2.0.4" from pug-code-gen@2.0.3
          node_modules/pug-code-gen
            pug-code-gen@"^2.0.2" from pug@2.0.4
            node_modules/pug
              pug@"^2.0.4" from the root project
        constantinople@"^3.1.2" from pug-code-gen@2.0.3
        node_modules/pug-code-gen
          pug-code-gen@"^2.0.2" from pug@2.0.4
          node_modules/pug
            pug@"^2.0.4" from the root project
        constantinople@"^3.0.1" from pug-filters@3.1.1
        node_modules/pug-filters
          pug-filters@"^3.1.1" from pug@2.0.4
          node_modules/pug
            pug@"^2.0.4" from the root project
```

また、それまでのバージョンでも`ls`サブコマンドで依存ツリーは確認できます。

```
$ npm ls core-js
app@1.0.0 /app
`-- pug@2.0.4
  `-- pug-code-gen@2.0.3
    `-- constantinople@3.1.2
      `-- babel-types@6.26.0
        `-- babel-runtime@6.26.0
          `-- core-js@2.6.12
```

さて、どうやらpugが間接的に(古い)babel-runtimeを使用しているため発生しているようです。でも、今のpugはbabel-runtimeに依存していません。なんで？

> pugをglobal install後、**ローカルにcliをインストールしたら**、変な警告が出た。

CLIをインストールした、おそらく[`pug-cli`](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-cli)のようです。よくみてください。このリポジトリ、5年間メンテされていません。

pug自体も半年以上コミットがなく気になるところですが、どうやら`pug-cli`は現在最新の`pug@3.0.2`ではなく、`pug@2.x`を使用したまま放置されているようです。

[update pug version · Issue #86 · pugjs/pug-cli](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-cli/issues/86)

このIssueによると、有志によるフォークが利用可能なようです。

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@anduh/pug-cli

Comment: ローカルにもグローバルにもいなかった場合、インストールしたパッケージ自体に付随している可能性があるのですね。勉強になりました。